# Using CF's as an extra key level? Is there a limit on tables/column famillies in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

As usual, I don't know if this is a good idea, so that's why I'm asking StackOverflow!

I'm toying with the idea of using CF's as an extra layer of partitioning data. For example, (and using the sensor example which seems to be pretty common) a traditional schema would be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  area_id int,
  sensor varchar,
  date ascii,
  event_time timeuuid,
  some_property1 varchar,
  some_property2 varchar,
  some_property3 varchar
  PRIMARY KEY ((area_id, sensor, date), event_time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time DESC);
```

This is a bit problematic if some_property1,2,3 etc are not known at design time and can be changed over the life the platform. One possibility is to just declare more properties as needed, but then I think it makes more sense to bring the sensors into their own CF as each will have different schemas. You could do this just by naming the CF something composite (managed outside Cassandra), e.g. {area_id}_{sensor_name}, and then alter the schema as needed when new properties are requested for insert.

My question is 2 fold. a) Is this a reasonable idea? and b) Are there any limitations of Cassandra (such as a cap of number of CFs) that this might fall foul of?

For reference this is a [possible design to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19818673/cassandra-time-sliced-data-model-for-unknown-data), but I think the question is valid to stand-alone.

Answer (score 2):

Andy,

Adding an excessively large number of column families will create maintainability issues for you down the road. I'd advise against it.

Consider using [CQL3 collections](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3_collections) to address the unknown property issue - these will allow your objects in this column family to have a variable number of properties that may not be known at design-time. You can use the Map type to give each of your dynamic properties a strong name and a correlated value (we do this.)

However, you if you need wildly different data types for each property and if you need more than 10-15 properties per sensor, then CQL3 collections might not be the right tool for the job. You can technically store up to 65,000 objects in a CQL3 collection, but the truth is that they should never approach that size. CQL3 collections aren't indexed and working with really large CQL3 collections will incur performance penalties.

Comment: What sort of maintainability issues would you forsee? If maintainability suffers for a gain in performance, then for what we are doing then I'm probably OK with that. 

Unfortunately CQL collections don't work very well for this task. The level of data per entry is going to be much higher than the data needed for querying. Each sensor may have n properties, but queries are ad-hoc on a subset of those. Cassandra requires the whole collection to be deserialised (or stored as a payload and the whole thing dumped on the wire for something else to deal with). In tests this didn't work out.

Comment: The biggest issue is that you'd need to have a lot of column-family specific query code for each CF, so the surface area of application code that you have to test and maintain will grow with each CF, versus being able to repurpose one.

Comment: Based on what you said though, I'd consider using two column families: an index column family which contains all of the data you need for querying and a pure storage column family that contains all of the heavy data. Have the index column family reference the storage column family.

We use this approach as well and it's remarkably flexible and performant.